# Finding the area of this figure inside a circle?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometry, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let's say I have a unit circle and I draw a *triangular* sector with an angle $\pi/2$. Next to it, I draw a sector with an angle $\pi/8$, next $\pi/18$, so that the $n^{\text{th}}$ sector has an angle of $\pi/(2n^2)$. Now I am only looking at the area of the triangle inside each sector. What is the area of the triangles if I were to draw infinitely many of them, as shown in the figure below?

I was only able to find an approximation for this. I got $f(1)/2 + \int_1^\infty f(x)dx$, where $f(x)=(1/2)\sin(\pi/(2x^2)) \approx 1.95$. How would you find the exact area of this?

[image]

Comment: Please make sure that my edit did not change your meaning.

Comment: I actually formulated the question wrong. I didn't mean sectors, I meant the triangle within the sector, meaning the isosceles triangle with sides along the sector, and with endpoints of the 3rd side on the circle. Do you think you could adjust the picture?

Comment: Ahh - I see. Is that better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you seem to know, the area of an isosceles triangle with common side length 1 and angle between them $\theta$ is $\sin(\theta)/2$.  Thus, your area is

$$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2 i^2}\right),$$

which is just a bit bigger than 1.  I don't see any easy reason to think that this is expressible in closed form; Mathematica, at least, can't seem to do so.

Comment: Yea I was able to approximate that like I said in my question, but I still have to find that integral in wolframalpha so it kindda defeats the purpose

Comment: @Ovi Well, there's any number of ways that you can approximate the infinite sum.  I just used the NSum command in Mathematica, but I do think your integral expression is quite nice, actually. Ultimately, the simple fact is that there are plenty of infinite sums for which no closed form expression exists.  That might very well be the case for this sum.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I got the approximation by calculating the area from 1 to infinity by taking intervals of 1 and splitting every interval into a rectangle and a right triangle, and by finding that area that way you actually end up with the series you need (f(1)+f(2)+...). I don't think my approximation is terribly accurate, but I guess I could make it more so by starting my integral from larger and larges values and accounting for it with the series.

Answer (score 2):

The union of the sectors should be a sector of angle
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi}{2n^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{\pi^3}{12}$$
and the area of a sector of angle $\theta$ in a circle of radius $r$ is $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\cdot\pi r^2$, so the area of the union of the sectors is
$$\frac{\pi^3/12}{2\pi}\cdot\pi=\frac{\pi^3}{24}$$

Comment: Sorry I formulated the question the wrong way. I didn't mean sectors, I meant the triangle within the sector, meaning the isosceles triangle with sides along the sector, and with endpoints of the 3rd side on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Area of a sector with angle $\theta$ is $\frac{\theta}{2}$ (Can you see this?).

Now, in your case, the area is given by

$ A = \sum_{x=1}^{x=\infty}\frac{\pi}{4x^{2}} = \frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}$

Do you know the value of the last sum? It is $\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$.

Comment: Well the area of a sector is (1/2)sin(x) so the formula x/2 would only be valid as x approaches 0, and not for the bigger sectors, right?

Comment: Here $\theta$ is in radian measure. The are of the full circle is $\pi$ and the full circle has radian measure $2\pi$. So, for a sector with angle $\theta$, the area is $\frac{\theta}{2}$ for every $\theta$ not only close to zero.

Comment: Sorry I formulated the question the wrong way. I didn't mean sectors, I meant the triangle within the sector, meaning the isosceles triangle with sides along the sector, and with endpoints of the 3rd side on the circle.

Comment: If you meant the triangle and not the sector, then the analysis will change

Comment: Yes I know, is there a way to find the exact area of the triangles withouth going into complicated summations?

Answer (score 1):

The resulting shape is a sector of the circle.  It would be helpful to find the central angle of this sector.  This angle is equal to the following sum:

$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{18}+\ldots=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\ldots\right)$$

Now here is a rather astonishing fact: the term inside the parentheses is equal to $\pi^2/6$.  This means we'd like to find the area of the sector of a unit circle ($r=1$) with central angle $\theta=\pi^3/12$.  The area is then given by:

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot r\cdot\theta=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1\cdot\frac{\pi^3}{12}=\frac{\pi^3}{24}$$

Comment: Sorry I formulated the question the wrong way. I didn't mean sectors, I meant the triangle within the sector, meaning the isosceles triangle with sides along the sector, and with endpoints of the 3rd side on the circle.